# PHP | Размер файла в scandir и убрать точки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Нужно во второй столбец таблицы записывать размер файла.
Также необходимо убрать точки ("." и "..") в конце списка. Вот код:

```
<body>
<table class="bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>Название файла</th>
        <th>Размер</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
$dir  = 'downloads';
$files = scandir($dir,1);
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
echo '<tr><td><a download href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/downloads/'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></td>    <td></td></tr>';
}
?>     

</table>
</body>
```

Благодарю.

Comment: точки можно в цикле легко отбросить, размер файла тоже [легко получается](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filesize.php)

Comment: @BOPOH, буду очень признателен, если сможешь итоговый код написать

Comment: @Rasrow, тут не делают работу за автора вопроса. Что вы сделали сами, и что не получилось?

Comment: @Sergiks сделал так

    echo '<tr><td><a download  href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/downloads/'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></td>    <td>'.filesize($value).'</td></tr>';

но не работает, в списке, где точки показывает 4096

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Получить список файлов в директории и убрать одинарную и двойную точки можно так (из комментариев к [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php)):

```
$files = array_diff( scandir( $dir), array('..', '.'));
```

Размер файла получается ф-ей [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filesize.php) - по одному файлу за вызов.

Ссылку вы можете указывать относительно, без `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` – просто начинать её со слеша.

PHP часть можно переписать так:

```
$dir  = 'downloads';
$files = array_diff( scandir( $dir), array('..', '.'));
foreach($files AS $i => $filename) {
    printf(
        '<tr><td><a download href="/downloads/%s">%s</a></td><td>%dB</td></tr>',
        urlencode( $filename),
        $filename,
        filesize( $dir . '/' . $filename)
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = scandir($dir);
unset($arr[0],$arr[1]);
sort($arr);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?